# Proof of $A = \emptyset \Leftrightarrow f(A) = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As far as I understood, $A = \emptyset \Rightarrow f(A) = \emptyset$ holds true for all functions, but the inverse $f(A) = \emptyset \Rightarrow A = \emptyset$ is only true, if $f(A)$ is injective. Is that so?

Comment: No, the second implication holds true for all functions

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with f being injective, what is your definition of a function?

Comment: This would make more sense with $f^{-1}(A)$  in place of  $f(A)$ and "surjective" in place of  "injective". Are you sure you got the statement right?

Answer (score 5):

No, $f(A)=\emptyset$ always implies $A=\emptyset$.

The set $f(A)$ is defined as $f(A)=\{f(a) \mid a \in A\}$. Suppose that in fact $A \neq \emptyset$, so there exists at least one $a \in A$. Then $f(a) \in f(A)$, so $f(A) \neq \emptyset$. Contradiction.

Comment: What if $A \not \subset$ domain of $f$?  What is $\sqrt{(\{\text{vegetarian fauna of the Amazon Rain Forest}\})}$?

Comment: @fleablood Writing $f(A)=\emptyset$ implies $f(A)$ is well-defined, which it only is for $A$ contained in the domain.

Comment: Or less absurd.   If $f(x) = \arcsin x$ then what is $f([2,10])$?  Is it meaningful to talk of that?  As $\arcsin: [-1,1]\to [-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2]$ does in make sense to even talk about $f([2,10])$ when $[2,10]\not \subset  [-1,1]$?

Comment: @Wojowu That's what I would think but I'm not certain we are correct.  Are we?  For instance: If $f(x) =\sqrt {x}$ as a real function.  If someone said $f(\{-100,-81,-36\}) =\emptyset$ would they be wrong?  Or would it depend on their working definition of "real function"?

Comment: @fleablood $\sqrt{x}$ is a *partial* function $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$. A function must be defined on all points of its domain by definition. We often elide that distinction in analysis because we can get away with it, but it's still an important one.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I agree.  But when when we elide and "get away" with $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ being a partial function, can we not equally elide and get away with $f(A) = \emptyset\implies A\subset \text{domain}^c$ for *partial* functions?  But ... I'm with you that if we are talking about *functions* it behooves us to use the definition properly.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f: X\to Y$

If $x \in A\subset X$ then $f(x)$ exists and $f(x) \in f(A)$.  So $f(A)$ is not empty.

So $A\ne \emptyset \implies f(A) \ne \emptyset$.  And contrapositively $f(A) = \emptyset \implies A = \emptyset$.

....

I suppose one can quibble that I haven't considered if $A\not \subset X$.  For instance if $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ via $f(x) = 3x^3 + \sin x$ what and $A = \{$ the 45 presidents of the united staes $\}$ what is $f(A)$?

Well, I may be wrong, but I don't actually think $f(A) =\emptyset$ simply because $3(\text{Jimmy Carter})^3 + \sin(\text{Jimmy Carter})$ is meaningless.  It's not not that $3(\text{Jimmy Carter})^3 + \sin(\text{Jimmy Carter})$ has no value; it's a meaningless expression and it'd be equally meaningless to say $f(A) = \emptyset$.... Maybe.  Maybe I am wrong and that is the exception.

......

But I can say with certainty that if $f(A) = \emptyset$ then $A\cap X = \emptyset$.

If we are talking about *partial* functions (which is an abuse of terminology) such as $f(x) =\sqrt{x}$ and we talk of $f(\{-27,16,25,-81\}) = \{4,5\}$ (which we *shouldn't* but if we do...)

Than I'd conclude $f(A) = \emptyset \implies A \subset (\text{domain of} f)^c$.

However with actual *properly* defined functions; if $f:X \to Y$ we have the domain of $f$ is $X$ and $X^c = \emptyset$.